How to get the second lowest value of a list item in a complex array
I currently have this solution working in my file to return the minutes until the soonest bus departure for a given route from an api call and thend display it:
soonestDepartureTimeUnix = min(item["departure_time"] for item in tsl105513Route2["itineraries"][0]["schedule_items"])
minutes = int((soonestDepartureTimeUnix - (time.time()))/60)

However, This is not so useful for passerby when the minutes value = 0.
For context this is what the response of the API call looks like:
{
    "route_departures": [
        {
            "global_route_id": "TSL:105513",
            "itineraries": [
                {
                    "branch_code": "",
                    "direction_headsign": "*******",
                    "direction_id": 1,
                    "headsign": "******",
                    "merged_headsign": "******",
                    "schedule_items": [
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1713461520,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": false,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13811798",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1713461520,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:45069396:369:5:15",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1713463320,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": false,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13811799",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1713463320,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:45069396:369:5:16",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1713465120,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": false,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13811800",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1713465120,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:45069396:369:5:17",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "mode_name": "Bus",
            "real_time_route_id": "30048",
            "route_color": "2a61a0",
            "route_long_name": "******",
            "route_network_id": "TransLink|Vancouver",
            "route_network_name": "TransLink",
            "route_short_name": "**8",
            "route_text_color": "ffffff",
            "route_type": 3,
            "sorting_key": "***",
            "tts_long_name": "*****",
            "tts_short_name": "*** "
        }
    ]
}

I have tried a variety of solutions including just jumping to the next item in the array:
if minutes < 1:
            soonestDepartureTimeUnix = (item["departure_time"] for item in tsl105513Route2["itineraries"][1]["schedule_items"])
            minutes = int((soonestDepartureTimeUnix - (time.time()))/60)

But this returned a "list item out of range" error.
I also tried this:
if minutes < 1:
            soonestDepartureTimeUnix = (item["departure_time"] for item in tsl105513Route2["itineraries"][0]["schedule_items"][1])
            minutes = int((soonestDepartureTimeUnix - (time.time()))/60)

but I got an error saying that the subtraction operation can't be done between a generator and a float.
Finally I tried this solution that I found for retrieving the second lowest list item that I found in an article:
if minutes < 1:
            soonestDepartureTimeUnix2 = min(item["departure_time"] for item in                tsl105513Route2["itineraries"][0]["schedule_items"] if item != soonestDepartureTimeUnix)
           minutes = int((soonestDepartureTimeUnix2 - (time.time()))/60)

However this just returns 0 again.

How can it possibly be correct to test minutes before you assign it?

In the generator, ignore any times before or equal to the current time.
minAllowedDepartureTimeUnix = time.time() + 60
soonestDepartureTimeUnix = min(item["departure_time"] 
                               for item in tsl105513Route2["itineraries"][0]["schedule_items"]
                               if item["departure_time"] >= minAllowedDepartureTimeUnix)

